# Package from Ubuntu Software Center not seen in apps

Tags: wireless

I'm really new to the whole Linux scene. 
I'm trying to get my downloaded Broadcom Wlan driver hooked up and running on Ubuntu.

I found a program that supposedly assists in doing the trick and it's called Windows Wireless Drivers (Found on the Ubuntu Software Center.)

Everything was going great until I downloaded the utility and installed and searched for it in my apps and nothing showed up. 
I've deleted and re-installed it several times with no luck in finding it through the "Search your computer and online resources" button up at the top of my distro.
I searched "Windows wireless drivers on the whole computer via the file search option in the computer file viewer and still no luck. 
Are there some commands to download and execute the file via command prompt? I'm not too familiar with the linux dialect so I wouldn't know where to start on getting the package via command prompt.

I'm running the most updated version of Ubuntu, as I updated everything yesterday. 
Any smart suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to install the Broadcom Wireless drivers via terminal instead.

Make sure you have a Broadcom Wireless Card (BCMxxxx). You can check for the same using

`sudo lshw -c network`

To install the Broadcom drivers via the Terminal

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source dkms`

Comment: This worked and it was so easy. I thought it would be way harder. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

`Windows Wireless Drivers` is a front-end package for `ndiswrapper`, which I have not needed to learn to use.  There is a tutorial on it at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Comment: And it is doubtful that ndiswrapper is correct for your Broadcom.